# Which triggers first: steel trap or health pack?

Tags: overwatch

If a Junkrat's steel trap is placed directly on top of a health pack and a low health hero lands on them (or more likely a Sombra teleports to them) would they be damaged by the trap and die or be healed by the health pack first and survive?

Edit: I suppose this might also be applicable to Widowmaker's venom mine but could have different results.

Comment: Judging from all my other experiences in Overwatch dying while touching health kits, the trap will take effect first.  However, I haven't actually tested it.

Comment: As they have different hit boxes it would depend on exactly where the trap is. If it really is directly on top of the health kit then you would probably hit the trap first walking straight into it. If you were to jump or fall onto the health kit you might hit it before the trap.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill, I suppose trap hitbox is much higher than visual representation, because it's often difficult to just simply jump over a trap. Besides, if trap's hitbox is small it would be inconvenient to use it.

Comment: @Exerion It's actually impossible to jump over junkrat's trap!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is dependent on which area of effect you enter first, if you enter both simultaneously (i.e. with Sombra's translocator) the health pick-up will trigger first.**

A 5hp Sombra translocates onto a Health pickup:
[image: Low health Sombra translocating onto Health pickup]

Notice how the Sombra heals to full, and *then* has damage from Junkrat's trap applied.

[Larger gfycat of above gif.](https://gfycat.com/DistinctOffensiveAmethystinepython)

Comment: But is this because the health pack *actually* triggers first, or because Sombra's invincibility during teleportation *stops* the trap from triggering first? Maybe we need to try other characters like Reaper to see how consistent the results are.

Comment: I suspect Reaper will pick up the health pick-up first as well. If he wraith forms onto it he will be un-trappable when he first touches the health kit, and if he shadow steps onto it he is un-trappable as his body comes out of the ground and he reforms. I can give it a go next time I have my testing group together but it might be a while.

Comment: What we need is a character that 1. teleports, 2. immediately appears at the destination point without physically covering any of the interim space (or they'll touch the health kit too early), and 3. is not invincible at the instant of reappearance. The question is whether Reaper/Sombra meet #3 or not (I don't think we know for sure).